# Page transitions in meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I've got a meteor mobile app *structurally* working; I really need to stitch the views together with some page transitions.

I looked at the [iron-transitioner](https://github.com/tmeasday/iron-transitioner) project but it looks like development has ceased? (last commit 6 months ago, still using Spark engine)

I've also looked at a few UI 'mobile frameworks' (Ratchet, Framework7) but I couldn't get them to play nicely with the meteor server.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any other simple (left/right) page transition package / script that I could try? It's just to give my UI some (expected) slickness really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about some jQuery with IronRouter?

```
Router.configure({
  load: function() {
    $('.content').animate({
      left: "-1000px",
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 400, function() {
        $(this).animate({ left: "0px" }, 400);
    });
});
```

What I also do to make a smooth transition between pages is to use a simple fadeIn/fadeOut.

```
Router.configure({
  load: function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 400);
    $('.content').hide().fadeIn(800);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Julien, that's a nice simple approach! I'd like to employ some CSS3 transitions where possible as they'll be smoother, and I'd also like to give direction instructions. Perhaps I need to write a function that I can pass some info to (transition, element etc)? Should I still try to use that within the load method? eg `load: pageTrans('left', '#mainContent')` ?

Comment: Yes, I think that the load method is the perfect place to do something like that. :)

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you. The blaze branch is up to date: https://github.com/percolatestudio/iron-transitioner/tree/blaze

Comment: The iron transitioner branch hasn't changed since I posted this question though, the last check-in was 22 days ago (May 7th) and still refers to the old {{yield}} etc

Comment: Ah ok. I managed to get the transistions working very easy with that package. However, the options were somewhat limited. Transistioning between different routes are not possible. Did you manage to get everything working with CSS3 animations?

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899318/meteor-with-mobile-front-end-ui-framework). Let us know how the above JQ method works out! Perpahs if you add [transit.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) you'll get nice hardware transitions.
FWIW I think the Percolate team are using a version of IronTransitioner for their Verso mobile app, which has some nice CSS3 transitions. Did you try the [IronTransitioner](https://github.com/tmeasday/iron-transitioner/tree/devel) package? As you say /devel/ even hasn't been touched for 6 months.

EDIT [percolateStudio fork of IT](https://github.com/percolatestudio/iron-transitioner/tree/blaze) has this comment "Alright, pretty much seems to be working with blaze."

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library and adding animate classes to the main content in your templates. My 'main' templates now look like this:

```
<template name='home'>
{{> navbar}}

<div class="container animated fadeIn" id="content">
    {{> startBox}}
</div>

{{> notification}}

<div id='background-image'></div>
<div id='background-color'></div>

{{> footer}}</template>
```