# meteor with mobile front-end UI framework

Tags: jquery-mobile, meteor, ionic-framework

Has anyone integrated meteor with mobile front-end frameworks?

In making mobile html5 apps look "more native" there are a number of CSS/front-end frameworks. eg:

- Meteoric http://meteoric.github.io/
- http://onsenui.io/
- http://topcoat.io/
- http://jquerymobile.com/ (shudder)
- http://goratchet.com/one.html
- http://ionicframework.com/
- App.js: http://code.kik.com/app/2/index.html
- http://lungo.tapquo.com/
- http://famo.us/
- http://goratchet.com/
- http://www.idangero.us/framework7/
- [Foundation for apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/)

and more. In comparison to plain Bootstrap, the main benefits are:

- preloading content
- smooth full-screen page navigation
- mobile widgets with "native look" for ios/android

But these frameworks often have use their own MVC model, for example pre-loading content into offscreen DIVs and doing full-screen transitions. they often use an internal router or Pushstate which would conflict with Meteor/IronRouter. And ionic for example depends on angular...

Has anyone had success with this type of integration? Any leads appreciated.

Comment: [famous](https://famo.us) link broke

Comment: for those who closed the question, this was meant to be a comprehensive answer to gather all the options together. I get points everyday from people who find this question useful, so i'd suggest it should be left open.

Answer (score 16):

Meteoric 
http://meteoric.github.io/
is a port of ionic, to remove the Angular stuff, and make some UI parts reactive. EDIT: not being updated now that angular is an option to jam into meteor itself.

related article:
https://medium.com/space-camp/cross-platform-uis-for-mobile-meteor-apps-6f12b583b205

this does seem like a great solution for mobile, but won't help if you want one UI to be responsive across to desktop devices too. they have deliberately kept the grid simple and mobile focused.

Comment: Yah, to remove the Angular junk +1 for this

Comment: wow, this is awesome, just what I was looking for!

Comment: I downvoted for I don't think it's appropriate to call something "junk" just because you don't like it or don't find it useful to you.

Comment: I didn't downvote, because the answer was useful, even if opinionated. But Billy also has a point, so I upvoted both the answer and the comment.

Comment: i updated about angular since MDG has chosen to bow to political pressure and enable it for meteor. beginning of the end IMHO, but to each his own.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, you are interested in any cases of mobile front-end framework integration with meteor.

Let me show you great example [famo.us](http://famo.us/) + meteor from Percolate Studio - guys who are doing a lot of stuff with meteor and for meteor too. [Here](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/06/03/meteor-famous-mobile) announce in meteor blog, also [video from devshop](http://youtu.be/bmd-cXSGQAA)

Some useful links in blog and devshop will be a good example of successful mobile+meteor integration in production app.

Comment: famous is promising, but isn't really ready for primetime yet. i added it and then removed it from my projects.

Answer (score 2):

Ratchet is available as an atmosphere package. It does not include all the javascript parts of the framework but very handy nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

[meteor-ionic](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic)

It uses the [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)

Comment: now known as meteoric. yes, this looks to have some of the right ingredients.

Comment: Unfortunately this package is not maintained anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

[Bootcards](http://bootcards.org/) is very good choice it's not meteor package yet .

[Ratchet](http://goratchet.com/) is  lightweight but also good choice .

Comment: I love the idea of cards UIs, but bootcards is really a very thin layer on top of bootstrap for grouping elements. for that to be meaningful, something like a carousel/rolodex/coverflow/stack navigation widget for the cards would be needed also. and then we get to the issue of including a bunch of plugins to get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

another new contender is Materialize which is a CSS/JS version of the material design elements, ie no angular required:

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize

here's a blog on some of the basics
http://blog.differential.com/the-easy-way-to-add-material-design-to-your-meteor-app/

### pros

- Materialize seems to have a decent set of widgets, and nice animations.

### cons

- pure android look, don't expect any appstore feature love
- no full-page transitions out of the box, like meteoric

Answer (score 0):

From the general goal sense, the front end part of Meteor somewhat conflicts with Angularjs. However, nothing is impossible if you really want to make them together. To accommodate them together, you need to do some special tricks. This following [post](https://medium.com/@zfxuan/the-wonderful-duo-using-meteor-and-angularjs-together-4d603a4651bf) shared the experience to make them working together.

[mrt:ionic](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/ionic) is the package by integrating meteor and ionic together. But it does not support the latest meteor version. You'd better wait for some time for the update.

Comment: I don't want to bring angular into my project, just for a CSS library...

Answer (score 0):

Foundation for Apps from Zurb is another option, but it's built on Angular so would have to be ported/hacked about in the same way the Ionic project was.

http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/