# page transitions in meteor - not quite working?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, velocity.js

so in the back of the 'discover meteor' book they explain how to do page transitions. i've got it working, however it causes problems with the loading of javascript functions and variables on other pages that its animating into. it seems they're not ready or simply don't exist at the time the page is routed.

```
Template.layout.onRendered(function() {
this.find('.pos-rel')._uihooks = {
    insertElement: function(node, next) {
        $(node).hide().insertBefore(next)
        .delay(200)
        .velocity("transition.slideUpIn", 1000)            
    },
    removeElement: function(node) {
        $(node).velocity({
            opacity: 0,             
        }, 
        {
        duration: 100,
            complete: function() {
                $(this).remove();               
            }
        });           
    }
}
});
```

if i remove the above code then all my javascript variables and functions work correctly. does anyone have another working solution to page transitions using velocity.js ? i did find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679204/page-transitions-in-meteor) but its a year old and i couldn't get it to work at all, it just makes the content where '{> yield}' is go blank :(

Comment: also .. found this https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-transitioner which seems to do exactly the same as above but as a package.. however i still get the same troubles :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note for asking questions on stack overflow: "causes problems with the loading of javascript functions and variables" is pretty vague. Its best to give more specifics.

But anyways, you said [here](https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-transitioner/issues/11) that you're using isotope to render items in a grid. I'm assuming you're calling `$elements.isotope()` within a `Template[name].onRendered` callback.

This is probably the issue because its trying to compute and rearrange into a grid the elements while they're hidden. Using `display: none` actually removed the elements, thus isotope can't compute the sizes, etc. for the layout. Try this:

```
insertElement: function(node, next) {
    $(node).css("opacity", 0).insertBefore(next)
    .delay(200)
    .velocity("transition.slideUpIn", {duration:1000, display:null})            
},
```

`opacity: 0` should do what you're looking for. It will make them transparent without removing them from the `transition.slideUpIn` should animate opacity so you're good there.

Also, velocity transitions mess with the display property. Setting `display: null` in the animation options prevents it from setting the display to block or whatever it wants to do. This may or may not be necessary, but I pretty much always use it.

Comment: hi chet, totally understand regarding the vague nature of my post, apologies. thanks for the answer.. this works brilliantly! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

> onAfterAction
>
> onBeforeAction

. The solution should be something like this:

```
 animateContentOut = function() {
     $('#content').css('display', 'none');
     this.next();
}

 fadeContentIn = function() {
  $('#content').velocity('transition.fadeIn',1000);
}
  Router.onBeforeAction(animateContentOut)
  Router.onAfterAction(fadeContentIn)
```